# Drag and drop image in landscape does not work

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following code to drag and drop an image over another image.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class DragImg: UIImageView {

    var originalPosition: CGPoint!
    var dropTarget: UIView?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        originalPosition = self.center
    }

    override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.locationInView(self.superview)
            self.center = CGPointMake(position.x, position.y)
        }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first, let target = dropTarget {
            let position = touch.locationInView(self.superview)
            if CGRectContainsPoint(target.frame, position) {
                let notif = NSNotification(name: "onTargetDropped", object: nil)
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notif)
            }
        }
        self.center = originalPosition
    }   
}
```

In portrait mode this works well, but if I change to landscape mode and try to drag and drop the image, the system does not recognises the image as being over the destination image. Can you explain me why and point out a possible solution?

Comment: did touchesMoved calls in landscape mode?

Comment: Yes, it is. But the problem is in touchesEnded, since the following condition does not returns true:  
`if CGRectContainsPoint(target.frame, position) {
                let notif = NSNotification(name: "onTargetDropped", object: nil)
                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotification(notif)
            }`  
I have printed target.frame and position and the result was:  
Position: (-254.0, 169.5)   
Target.frame: (122.0, 44.0, 423.0, 277.0).

Comment: Do `self` and `target` have the same `superview`?

Comment: @robmayoff How can I see that? But I think so, since in portrait it works.

Comment: `print(self.superview, target.superview)` in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`.

Comment: @robmayoff in both portrait and landscape, "self" comes from a StackView and "target" from UIView. But my doubt is why this works in portrait and not in landscape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say precisely what is happening without seeing more of your view hierarchy, but you say that `self` and `target` have different superviews. This means that their frames are in different coordinate systems. Each view defines its own coordinate system. Those coordinate systems may happen to line up at times, and rotating the user interface may change whether two views' coordinate systems line up.

The `frame` of a view has meaning only in the coordinate system of the view's `superview`. You're computing `position = touch.locationInView(self.superview)`, so `position` is in the coordinate system of `self.superview`. Then you're asking if `CGRectContainsPoint(target.frame, position)`, but `target.frame` is in a different coordinate system, so the answer has no meaning in general.

The easiest way to see if `touch` is in `target` is this:

```
let position = touch.locationInView(target)
if target.pointInside(position, withEvent: event) {
    // The touch is in the target.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, but I want to understand how this works, so if someone could explain me why this works I would appreciate. 
The solution that I have found is:
Changed this:

```
let position = touch.locationInView(self.superview)
```

To this:

```
let position = touch.locationInView(touch.view!.window)
```

.